# Sorted function

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

```
list=[(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]
def st(element):
    return (element[1])
print(sorted(list,key=st))
```

Can someone explain the working of this program? When return statement returns 5,2,4,3,1 to the sorted funtion how do we get the list of tuples sorted ?
Instead shouldn't the output be [1,2,3,4,5].Since only the second value returns to the sorted function.

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] your question and add the tag of the programming language that the code, in your question, is written in?

Answer (score 1):

The `sorted` function will sort the *list* (ie, the entire set of tuples) using the *function* `st()` to provide the keys for sorting. The `st()` function in no way limits what gets sorted, only what get used to decide *how* to sort.

You can think of it as you providing an answer to the question the `sorted` function needs answered for each element: What is the value for this element I should use when deciding where to put it?

The output is:

```
[(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (2, 5)]
```

which is the sorted list using the second item of each tuple to decide order.